# Error Object variable or With block variable not set only when Protected view activ

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the following done. When I open workbook in folder, it opens, runs code where new copy of this workbook is created in "TEMP" folder and the original is closed. The idea is to have multiple copies open at the same time and on closing, all user updates copy into the original.

Everything works well when when workbook is opened second time, however on first opening when in Protected view I get Run-time error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set.

I have read a good bit about this issue but can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim strFilename, strDirname, strDirname2, strPathname, strDefpath As String
 'Count files in folder
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim strDefpatheee As String
Dim strDirnameeee As String

strDirnameeee = "TEMP"

strDefpatheee = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
MyFolder = strDefpatheee & "\" & strDirnameeee
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\" & "*.xlsm")
Do While MyFile <> ""
    j = j + 1
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

 'Save as same name + count of files in folder TEMP
 On Error Resume Next ' If directory exist goto next line
strDirname = "TEMP" ' New directory name

strFilename = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5) & " " & j + 1 'New file name
strDefpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path 'Default path name
'If IsEmpty(strDirname) Then Exit Sub
'If IsEmpty(strFilename) Then Exit Sub

'MkDir strDefpath & "\" & strDirname
strPathname = strDefpath & "\" & strDirname & "\" & strFilename 'create total string

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPathname & ".xlsm", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
Sheets("ACTIONS").Range("BG2").ClearContents
Sheets("ACTIONS").Range("D6").Select
PasswordEntry.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim strFilename, strDirname, strDirname2, strPathname, strDefpath As String` This definition is assigning StreDefpath as String and remaining as Variants.

Comment: The j integer have no initial value.

Comment: Exactly, where are you getting the error?

Comment: I can see where the error comes up exactly. The project is not visible at that point and I don't get optin to debug. I can only get help or end.

Comment: With just your description and code, it is hard to replicate what is wrong.

Comment: What I was doint to get the protected view to activate was uploading it google drive and download ing it again. I know I have given little bit of info but hopefully will get to the bottom of this.

Comment: i have been able to get the error to come up and it is `strDefpatheee = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` Any suggestion for fix?